# How to convert a time string to integer in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have time data that is currently a string in the format of hours:minutes:seconds. For example, I want to be able to convert the string 00:03:30 to 210 seconds. I'd like this to be created in a calculated field for total seconds, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Utilizing the [DATEPARSE](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/data_dateparse.htm#create-a-calculation-using-the-dateparse-function) function, you can use the following expression:

`datediff("second", dateparse("HH:mm:ss", "00:00:00"), dateparse("HH:mm:ss", "00:03:30"))`

Replace `"00:03:30"` with your field.